# OpenLDAP: Why would you ever use refreshOnly for replication?

Tags: openldap, replication

I'm reading about OpenLDAP replication and I don't understand why you would use refreshOnly mode vs. refreshAndPersist mode.

I've tried to do some searching online, but wasn't able to find any discussion on the benefits (if any) of refreshOnly.

[This page says](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch7/#ol-syncrepl-mm) "In this configuration, assuming that a refreshAndPersist type of synchronization is used (it is not clear why you would even want to think about using refreshOnly but it is possible), then a write (modify) to any master will be immediately propagated to all the other masters (providers) acting in their slave (consumer) role."

But's it's referring to Multi-Master replication and doesn't say anything similar for Provider/Consumer replication.

Is there any reason why I should ever consider refreshOnly for OpenLDAP replication?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick idea: to limit network traffic to the specific points in time when the client wants to do the synchronization. For example: if you have a dial-up connection, and you don't want to keep your network connection up continuously, refreshOnly would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use it when you want complete control over the timing of replication, e.g. once a day at midnight, as opposed to continuous replication.